# Reading variable sized columns in a matrix

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I have a file that contains different columns in different lines. For example

```
10 20 30 60 
60 20 90 100 40 80
20 50 60 30 90
....
```

I want to read the last three numbers in each row. So the output will be

```
20 30 60 
100 40 80
60 30 90
```

I can not use the following structures because of variable size in each line

structure 1:

```
std::ifstream fin ("data.txt");
while (fin >> a >> b >> c) {...}
```

structure 2:

```
string line;
stringstream ss;
getline(fin, line);
ss << line;
int x, y, z;
ss >> x >> y >> z >> line;
```

What should I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read them into a `std::vector` and lop off everything but the last 3 items.

```
std::string line;
while (getline(fin, line))
{
    std::vector<int> vLine;
    istringstream iss(line);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(vLine));
    if (vLine.size() > 3)
    {
        vLine.erase(vLine.begin(), vLine.begin() + (vLine.size() - 3));
    }
    // store vLine somewhere useful
}
```

Comment: I have to first tokenize the line and the problem is, I don't know the exact number of tokens in each line